# 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: 'GoogleRefreshTokenClient' object has no attribute 'before_request' when trying to Upload clicks

Tags: python, google-api, google-ads-api

```
client_id, client_secret, developer_token = settings.CLIENT_ID, settings.CLIENT_SECRET, settings.DEVELOPER_TOKEN

credentials = oauth2.GoogleRefreshTokenClient(
    client_id,
    client_secret,
    login_user.refresh_token
)

client = GoogleAdsClient(credentials, settings.DEVELOPER_TOKEN)

click_conversion = client.get_type("ClickConversion")
conversion_action_service = client.get_service("ConversionActionService")
click_conversion.conversion_action = (
    conversion_action_service.conversion_action_path(
        client_id, company.conversion_name
    )
)

click_conversion.gclid = deal.gclid
click_conversion.conversion_value = float(deal.deal_value if deal.deal_value else 0)
click_conversion.conversion_date_time = make_aware(datetime.now()).strftime('%Y%m%d %H%M%S %z')

conversion_upload_service = client.get_service("ConversionUploadService")
request = client.get_type("UploadClickConversionsRequest")
request.customer_id = client_id
request.conversions.append(click_conversion)
request.partial_failure = True
conversion_upload_response = (
    conversion_upload_service.upload_click_conversions(
        request=request,
    )
)
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting the above error when trying to Upload Clicks to google ads? got this in the logs:

> Request made: ClientCustomerId: xxxxxx-xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com, Host: googleads.googleapis.com, Method: /google.ads.googleads.v11.services.ConversionUploadService/UploadClickConversions, RequestId: None, IsFault: True, FaultMessage: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: 'GoogleRefreshTokenClient' object has no attribute 'before_request'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50446716/1841839  maybe this?

Comment: @DaImTo not too sure what I would do instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you're using the `googleads.oauth2.GoogleRefreshTokenClient` class, which was the way to create credentials in the `googleads` package for the Adwords API.

This class is no longer in used for the `google-ads` (Ads API) package, use `google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials` instead.

The easiest way is to use the utility function `google.ads.googleads.oauth2.get_installed_app_credentials()`:

```py
credentials = google.ads.googleads.oauth2.get_installed_app_credentials(
    client_id=client_id, 
    client_secret=client_secret,
    refresh_token=login_user.refresh_token
)
```